# Why don't GPS satellites experience power outage more often than they should?

Tags: gps, power-consumption, satellite

With the advent of smartphones I would believe that there's this huge exponential growth in number of GPS receivers around, and by now there should be an unaccountable number of devices on earth taking signals from GPS satellites in outer space.

Is the number of receivers (or devices) in use proportional to the power consumption of GPS satellites in space? In a way that the satellites have to "work harder" or draw more current to provide more signals to that many receivers?

Comment: Does the power consumed by a lightbulb increase with the number of people looking at it?

Comment: Does a radio need more power as more people listen to it? (The volume isn't changed).

Comment: @Transistor, that analogy leads to more questioning. If I'm standing right behind a wall, then regardless of how much power the light bulb delivers I won't see the light since the wall "consumes" all the photon in that direction. In a sense that in radio or satellite transmission, if a receiver in close proximity "consumes" that electromagnetic waves, they my receiver would receive a weakening signal or no signal unless the transmitter "shoots" more EM waves in my direction, or wave with higher energy to be shared to ensure both receivers receive signal of sufficient energy to process?

Comment: @KMC the wall analogy: well, that only applies if you place another antenna *directly* between you and the satellite, in which case you'll be in the shadow of the antenna. Merely being nearby makes no difference.

Comment: @KMC seriously, you simply have a fundamentally flawed idea of how transmission and reception works. As soon as a wave leaves the vicinity of the transmitter, it's literally good and gone forever – there can't be **any** effect on the transmitter of how many receivers receive it. We don't know your mental model, but it's sadly wrong. Radio waves are, really, exactly like light (in fact, light and radio only differ in wavelength): Your lightbulb doesn't care how much readers are in a library. It still illuminates the same desks. We can make a million more analogies, to no avail.

Comment: @KMC you need to dump your faulty mental model and really understand there's no effect of the receiver on the transmitter.

Comment: And, you need to do bit of research into the fundamentals of how antennas work.  If an antenna (like what's on a GPS receiver) is further away from another antenna by approximately a wavelength or two at the frequency of interest, they interact with the incoming RF signal independently of one another.

Comment: Afaik your 'standing behind a wall' analogy does actually have some relevance here - in that a sufficiently 'large' radio antenna *will* block (or at least reduce the strength measurably) a signal from being received by receivers 'behind' it. This still has no effect on the transmitter though (unless the antenna is close enough to the transmitter that reflections couple back in interesting ways).

Comment: @brhans, sure the transmitter wouldn't know, but if there's a dummy receiver that checks for signal intensity then one can manually adjust satellite power delivery.  Like sharing a fan in a hot summer day, I would crank it up to get better share of the breeze if more people are standing in my way.  And like layering translucent sheets between a light source, I would increase the brightness to ensure sufficient light is being transmitted.

Comment: Again it's a sense of proportionality (negligible or not) that I see from pjc50's answer.  But as @SteveSh points out I probably need to dig deeper into antennas physics to find an accurate answer. but here I just wish for a conceptual understanding, be it quantitative or an (proper) analogy.

Comment: @KMC your fan analogy shows how wrong you are! You don't get less breeze because there's people next to you. **NO,** for the tenth time, there's no proportionality here. Stop claiming there is. **Literally** 8 people have told you the concept is "the transmitter doesn't draw more power because there's more receivers". You don't need another person to state the same, really. The conceptual answer has been given, several times now. We can't confirm your preconceptions, they are completely wrong, sorry!

Comment: The first comment you've gotten has the proper analogy you're still asking for: a lightbulb doesn't draw any more power if people are looking at it.

Comment: @pjc50 could you do me the favour and repeat that your answer is **not** that there's a proportionality of power usage of the transmitter and number of receivers, please? KMC is still misinterpreting things.

Comment: @KMC your "people standing in the way" and "transparent sheets" arguments are the wrong thing again; you don't need more fan if someone is *next* to you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller their misinterpretation is almost reaching the level of trolling

Comment: @pjc50 you're right. I think I will just leave this question alone then, for a while, seeing that they've even removed the acceptance from your (good!) answer – at this point, I think KMC would rather have confirmed what they believe to be true than to learn the actual truth, and while I think they (as much as us) will get over that, I shouldn't spend more energy on this.

Answer (score 8):

GPS satellites only transmit. They don't care about anyone receives them. How should they even know?

You don't need more power to reach more receivers – since you don't know where people need GPS, you need to illuminate the whole surface of the earth with your signal, anyway.

I think a fair analogy would be "does the moon need to reflect more light if more people are looking at it?".

> Why don't GPS satellites experience power outage?

Um, pardon me? If a satellite like that experiences a power outage, that's a failure of an order-of-magnitude USD 10⁸ system, and really shouldn't ever happen, or someone has some reliability model to overhaul.

Comment: And **if** one or more GPS satellites break (stop transmitting) the system doesn't immediately stop working. As long as there are **enough** satellites in operation, the system will work.

Comment: If the transmitted signal is shared by more devices, wouldn't the signal "disappeared" in a way that each receiver consumes part of the transmitted signal? I think there's something  very fundamental that I'm not understanding.

Comment: @KMC Think of it like this: I have a bottle, and I'm pouring water from it. You can put a glass under the stream of water, to catch some of it, or you can just let it fall to the ground. You having a glass catching the water I'm pouring out does not affect what is happening with the bottle. It's the same way with broadcasting: Signal is always coming out, going in the directions of the radiation pattern of the antenna, and it doesn't matter if you catch some of that radiation with your GPS receiver's antenna or not.

Comment: Exactly, AndrejaKo! That's why I used the moon analogy: Whether or not someone looks at the moon, the light will be absorbed by something (or scattered back to space), the moon doesn't have to shine brighter when more people are looking.

Comment: @KMC Earth surface absorb much more energy of signals than all of antennas.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, with more glasses catching the water, eventually there will be some glasses not catching any of that water (or signal) and you'll have to pour more water (energy) to fill them up. Same for the moon analogy, if and for the sake of argument, there are enough objects reflecting the light, it'll be so crowded that someone will not find a place to observe the moon.  It really is a function of surface area and how much it is occupied.  So eventually there will be so many smartphones that some phones will not receive the GPS signals and the satellites has to draw more power to deliver.

Comment: @KMC sorry, even covering the entire surface of the globe a meter deep in smartphones won't make a difference

Comment: @KMC It is indeed a function of the surface area. This gets complicated quite quickly, so I'll introduce a simplification: Let's assume that the transmitter is using an isotropic antenna (theoretical antenna model which radiates equally in all directions). The volume covered by such transmitter is a ball. At a certain distance D from the transmitter, there is a sphere, with radius D, where across whole of its surface you have same signal strength. If you were to completely cover the inside of the sphere with receive antennas, then you'd catch all of the signal.

Answer (score 3):

Let's get some numbers!

[This paper quotes example transmit power numbers of 50-300W](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334442881_GPS_and_GLONASS_Satellite_Transmit_Power_Update_for_IGS_repro3) depending on which generation the satellite is. Or about half the power of a cheap microwave oven.

[This random web page](http://gpsinformation.net/main/gpspower.htm) claims the free space loss from orbit as being 182 dB. That is a *lot*. Well over 99.99% of the power is lost to space; someone more dedicated can calculate exactly how many nines to put there.

The received power in miliwatts (after converting from the confusing-to-layman unit dBw) appears to be about 5 × 10<sup>-12</sup> W.

So (if I've got my powers of ten right) one transmitter power is roughly equal to a quadrillion receivers.

In re: "does a receiver consumes energy given by the satellite?", we have to be careful. Does a receiver consume energy from its antenna? Yes. Did that energy come from the satellite? Yes. Does removing/turning off the transmitter remove that input energy? Yes. Does removing the receiver change the power consumption in the transmitter? **No**.

Comment: I just can't relate any analogy to my understanding.  Nice quantitative answer to get a sense of proportionality. I should be asking the question: does a receiver consumes energy given by the satellite?  Thanks!

Comment: while correct in spirit, there's a few things wrong about this answer: Free-Space path loss is not power lost in space, it's just the reduction of power per area due to the illuminated area growing with the square of distance from the satellite, but the satellite still only illuminates earth, so these 182 dB aren't "lost", they're just the "stretching out the one transmit power over a large swath of ground".

Comment: The receiver "consumes" energy from the incoming RF signal that impinges upon, and is captured by the receiver's antenna.  The transmitter doesn't know, nor does it care, about this captured energy.

Comment: Even if we plastered earth in 1000 times the number of receivers pjc50 calculates here, the GPS satellite still wouldn't notice. It can't. There's no effect of the receiver on the transmitter if they are apart more than a wavelength! @KMC I hope you're taking "the **received** power would go down if we plastered the surface of earth in layers of GPS receivers" from this, and **not** "the effect on the transmitter is just to small, because we don't have *that* many receivers" from this. There's no effect on the transmitter! It doesn't notice whether earth is made of GPS receivers or cheese.

Comment: What would happen if more people used Glonass rather than GPS? Or Galileo? Or are these other systems stealing power from the GPS satellites?

Comment: "  I should be asking the question: does a receiver consumes energy given by the satellite? " @KMC  Yes, the receiver consumes energy given by the satellite.  The calculations by pjc50 shows the satellites produce enough power for quadrillions of receivers, they will not run out of power any time soon.

Comment: @MacGuffin agree, see edit

Answer (score 2):

> Is the number of receivers (or devices) in use proportional to the power consumption of GPS satellites in space?

No.

What this thread needs is a sports analogy.

You are a quarterback.  You throw footballs.  1 per second, all day, all night.  86,400 footballs per day, 24/7/365.  Over 30 million footballs per year.

But - you are a blind and deaf quarterback.  You have no idea who or what is around you.  Other than a general sense of direction, you do not know where the footballs are going.

And most importantly, you have absolutely zero idea of whether or not any of them are being caught, or what people are doing with them after they catch some.  But that has no effect on how many footballs you throw or how far they go.  Downtown Chicago or the middle of a desert, you just keep throwing footballs.